# angularfire 's $watch is not working on ios device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, firebase, cordova-plugins, angularfire

Angularfire's $watch method is not firing/triggering when ios app running in background on real device (iPad) but working fine when app is in foreground state. On ios simulator and android devices, its working fine in both conditions.

thanks

Comment: Please see [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

firebase connection is paused (as any web connection) when an app is in background. That's something you cannot prevent... However it should restart when the app is put back in foreground, and your watch should catch up the changes, since it's based on `.on('value'` calls.

Maybe you've overriden the `$$notify` or the `$$updated` function, preventing the listeners to be called ?

If not or as a workaround you may want to take a look at the offline capability of firebase listening on '.info/connected'

```
var onlineRef = $firebase.child('.info/connected');
onlineRef.on('value', function(snap){
  if (snap.val()){ // client is connected
    // [rewatch stuff here if needed]
  }
})
```

... [here is a nice source](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html) to get your started with offline capability

Comment: I am not agree that firebase connection get paused when app is in background because it is working fine on all android devices and ios simulators but not on ios real device :s...

Comment: the device pauses your app when not in foreground, and at first an image of the app is is shown while the app reload (and firebase reconnect), that's why it may be not really responsive for a sec, if you're using angularfire listen on the firebase:connected event, you'll see it by yourself

Comment: Yeah I agree somehow that firebase $watch is getting pause in background state. Let me try to keep it up using firebase library for ios. Thanks Nicolas.